# How to always open jscolor picker without clicking on button

Tags: jscolor

I am using Jscolor.I want to always open the jscolorpicker without clicking on button. I need to default open.

```
<button name="newreportcolor" id="reportchosecolor-btn" class="jscolor
                                                        {valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'styleInput',closable:true,hash:true,closeText:'Close me!',onFineChange:'selectcolor(this)'} ">
                                                        Choose Color
                                                       </button>
```